# If the same function is used in both if expression and if statement, does it get called twice?

Tags: php, if-statement

Does the following construct access the database twice?

```
$output = access_database() ? access_database() : NULL;
```

Should I be rather doing the following?

```
$result = access_database();
$output = $result ? $result : NULL;
```

Comment: You can test that, create a method that echos then put it in a construct like that, it will tell you what you need to know.

Comment: Regardless, you probably can just do `access_database() ?: NULL;`.

Comment: Not sure why you would do this, but if this is common then have `access_database()` return `NULL` instead of `false`.

Comment: In the question, I was referring to `access_database()` returning a string from DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this: `$result = access_database();` the `result` receives the value from the execution of your function, not a reference that will be executed when accessed.

So, yes the following line will execute your function two times:

```
$output = access_database() ? access_database() : NULL;
```

One option is use the [elvis operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator)(php version >= 5.3):

```
$output = access_database() ?: NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use this PHP syntax sugar to avoid that in your case.

```
$output = access_database() ? : NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks! How about `if (function() == 1 && function() == 2)`, is there sugar for that?

Comment: `in_array(function(), [1,2])`

Comment: If you don't have 5.3 try: `$output = ($result = access_database()) ? $result : NULL;`

Comment: @AbraCadaver, I never thought of wrapping it with the parentheses, thank you!